# element inside ngIf function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button that should appear only when ng-if statement is true
Can I pass the element in ng-if function? 
I'm trying to reach elements inside the DOM that are outside of the button's scope
without doing $scope.$parent.$parent....

```
<span class="iconFont smallClose" ng-if="isEdit($element)" ng-click="remove($index)"></span>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you post your code so we can see?

Comment: Sure. Added in question. Thanks

Comment: if you are using controller as syntax, you can reference elements outside without $scope.$parent.$parent

Comment: I have a controller that belongs to this scope and another controller that belongs to parents scope. I'm not sure how should I add it to the controller

Comment: Why don't you just add a property binding from parent to child?